# Why my time count of a system call in linux is almost 0 us?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system, system-calls

Nowadays, I'm working on a system kernel practice course. However, when I compare a system call with an user call, it's strange that the system call return a time count of 0 us (sometimes return 1). But I pass count=1e8 which is a quite big number.

I'm doubt that the computations didn't happen because the result is not used. Then I change add as result = result + 1 and print the final result. However, the result is right and the time count just from 0 or 1 change to 2-6.

```py
long yanpan_oper(int* result,int num1,int num2,char* op)
{
    if(op)
    {
        if(*op == '+')
        {
            *result = num1 + num2;
        }
        else if(*op == '-')
        {
            *result = num1 - num2;
        }
        else if(*op == '*')
        {
            *result = num1*num2;
        }
        else if(*op == '\\')
        {
            if(num2!=0)
                *result = num1/num2;
            else
                printk("divided number can't be zero!\n");
        }else
            printk("unrecongized operator %c\n", *op);
    }else
    {
        printk("operation is empty.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(yanpan_func, int, count)
{
    printk("The count is %d.\n", count);
    struct timeval tstart, tend;
    do_gettimeofday(&tstart);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<count;i++) // +
    {
        int result;
        char op_add = '+';
        yanpan_oper(&result, i, 10, &op_add);
    }
    for(i=0;i<count;i++) // -
    {
        int result;
        char op_sub = '-';
        yanpan_oper(&result, i, 10, &op_sub);
    }
    for(i=0;i<count;i++) // *
    {
        int result;
        char op_mul = '*';
        yanpan_oper(&result, i, 2, &op_mul);
    }
    for(i=0;i<count;i++) // '//'
    {
        int result;
        char op_div = '\\';
        yanpan_oper(&result, i, 10, &op_div);
    }
    do_gettimeofday(&tend);
    long delta_time = 1000000*(tend.tv_sec - tstart.tv_sec) + (tend.tv_usec - tstart.tv_usec);
    printk("The start time is %ld.\n", tstart.tv_sec*1000000+tstart.tv_usec);
    printk("The end time is %ld.\n", tend.tv_sec*1000000+tend.tv_usec);
    printk("Syscall time use:%ld usec", delta_time);
    return delta_time;
}
```

I have tried many times, but the result didn't change. The user call computation of the same amount takes around 1300 ms, can computations occur in kernel be fast like this?

Comment: I'm lacking a `main` function. Please produce a [mre]

Comment: Also, in the process of making it minimal, you can probably remove three loops from `SYSCALL_DEFINE1` and the three `else if` from `yanpan_oper`

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at one loop:

```
for(i=0;i<count;i++) // +
{
    int result;
    char op_add = '+';
    yanpan_oper(&result, i, 10, &op_add);
}
```

This will call the function yanpan_oper `count` times. But each time it will overwrite the previous result stored in `result` without using that value for the computation. Chances are that the compiler just optimized the whole loop away, replacing it with just one single call to `yanpan_oper` since the for loop is actually equivalent to just executing the loop body once.

Furthermore, the loop body ONLY affects variables inside the loop body, so not only can the compiler decide to just keep the last iteration. It can skip basically the whole code, so that what you're actually executing is this:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(yanpan_func, int, count)
{
    printk("The count is %d.\n", count);
    struct timeval tstart, tend;
    do_gettimeofday(&tstart);
    do_gettimeofday(&tend);
    long delta_time = 1000000*(tend.tv_sec - tstart.tv_sec) + (tend.tv_usec - tstart.tv_usec);
    printk("The start time is %ld.\n", tstart.tv_sec*1000000+tstart.tv_usec);
    printk("The end time is %ld.\n", tend.tv_sec*1000000+tend.tv_usec);
    printk("Syscall time use:%ld usec", delta_time);
    return delta_time;
}
```

Here are some tips for how to fool the optimizer:

```
// Create input that cannot be calculated at compile time
int input1[count];
int input2[count];
srand(time(NULL));
for(int i=0; i<count; i++) { 
    input1[i] = rand()%1000;
    input2[i] = rand()%1000;
}

// Store the output, so that the optimizer cannot take away the loop
int output[count];

// Start timer
for(i=0;i<count;i++) // +
{
    char op_add = '+';
    yanpan_oper(&output[i], input1[i], input2[i], &op_add);
}
// End timer

// Use the output to that the optimizer cannot remove the array, and thus
// also the loop
for(int i=0; i<count; i++) 
    printf("%d ", output[i]);
```

Do note that those arrays may be to big for the stack. If that's the case, use this instead:

```
int *input1 = malloc(count * sizeof(*input1));
int *input2 = malloc(count * sizeof(*input2));
srand(time(NULL));
for(int i=0; i<count; i++) { 
    input1[i] = rand()%1000;
    input2[i] = rand()%1000;
}

int *output = malloc(count * sizeof(*output));
```

(Remember to check if malloc succeeded and to free the memory afterwards)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. In fact, I have guessed the reason is the optimization of the compiler. As what I mentioned in question, I just change the code of addition to at every iteration, it does the addition : `yanpan_oper(&result, result, 1, op_add)`.  Finally, I print the result after all addition. But the time nearly have no change. I think the compiler cannot be so intelligence. That's why I felt strange about this.

Comment: With that code, you have UB since you have not initialized `result` and even if you do initialize it, the computation is still theoretically possible to compute at compile time.

Comment: A compiler is allowed to "optimize" calls to the function only if it is able to prove that the function has **no side effects**. While on certain values of input arguments `yanpan_oper` is actually has no side effects (not sure about output parameter `result`), I doubt that compiler is able to prove that. Without such proving, a compiler is never allowed to reduce loops: the resulted binary code calls `yanpan_oper` as many times as specified in the source code.

Comment: @Tsyvarev True, but why not make sure that the optimizer cannot do so instead of making wild guesses about how smart it is?

Comment: @Broman: Random values and especiall arrays of them looks like an ugly way for prevent compiler from code optimization. Of course, this are just my feelings. But in any case, it could be useful to check that **binary code**, generated from the **original sources**, actually drops the function calls. If it doesn't, then the problem of zero-time is somewhere else...

Comment: @Tsyvarev I agree that it is a bit ugly, but since this kind of code by it's nature is temporary I don't think it's such a big deal. But yes checking the binary code (or even better, the assembly code) is also a great thing to do.

Comment: @Broman I forget to say that: I used to print every result. Then the cost time can be very big. But what I am comparing is computational costs not output costs. So, maybe printing all result cannot be a proper method. I'm so frustrated about this experiment...

Comment: @yanpan Read my code again. There are no printouts in the code that is benchmarked. The clock stops before the prints. Also, read my [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56359402/why-my-time-count-of-a-system-call-in-linux-is-almost-0-us/56359593?noredirect=1#comment99324857_56359402) I wrote on your question.