# Prevent loop from beeing optimised

Tags: c, for-loop, gcc

I want to do a measurement of the runtime of a void function. Therefore I use a loop running 100_000 iterations of the same function to get a better average value.
How can I prevent GCC from optimising away my loop while still using -O3?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent GCC from optimizing out a busy wait loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083482/how-can-i-prevent-gcc-from-optimizing-out-a-busy-wait-loop)

Comment: Some tips and tricks https://stackoverflow.com/a/56359593/6699433

Answer (score 1):

You need to introduce something which will prevent the optimization (both in the function called and in the loop. The easiest is an `asm("")`

```
void __attribute__((noinline)) foo(void)
{
    asm("");
}

void bar(void)
{
    for(unsigned x = 0; x < 1000000;x++)
    {
        foo();
        asm("");
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1G4oP4jjr

Answer (score 0):

To prevent GCC from optimizing away your loop while still using -O3, you can use a volatile variable.
Using volatile tells the compiler that the variable may change unexpectedly, and adding the dummy operation inside the loop prevents it from being optimized away.

Comment: Adding an access of a `void` object inside the loop will prevent the compiler from removing thr loop and the accesses to the object, but it may not prevent the compiler from removing the calls to the function or hoisting the call out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can read here how to use pragma to do it around a specific function or how to use volatile qualifier to do it. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219829/how-can-i-prevent-gcc-optimizing-some-statements-in-c)

Another way is to set the optimiaztion level for that peice of code specifically:
`#pragma GCC optimize("O0")`